# Why on server is not running when i use bullmq?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, bullmq

When i try to use this code it's not logging Hello, World also i noticed that my server is not runninng on localhost 3000 what i'm doing wrong? using bullmq

trying to run a function after 10 seconds how to do that? using bullmq?

```
import { Queue } from 'bullmq';

const myQueue = new Queue('myqueue', {
    connection: {
        host: 'myhost',
        port: 4346,
        password: 'pass'
    }
});

const job = await myQueue.add('my-job', {});

const myFunction = () => {
    console.log('Hello World');
};

myQueue.process('my-job', (job) => {
    myFunction();
});

myQueue.resume();
```

Comment: show code for server start up

Comment: const port = 3000;
const app = express(); app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port ' + port);
})

Comment: Did you ever solve your issue? What was the cause?